# How is it possible that i get wrong class for my Session in onCreate()?

Tags: java, android, android-lifecycle

I have the strangest error in my Google play console. It only happened for one user and on one device (Galaxy XCover4), but still.

I have a custom Application object. In onCreate() i retrieve it. It's been like this for many years:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    appSession = (ApplicationSession) getApplication();//caused classcastexception!
}
```

Now, for my latest release, i got a classcastexception on the cast row in the google play console:

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException:    at xxx.onCreate
>   (xxxActivity.java:33)   at xxxActivity.onCreate (xxxActivity.java:64) 
>   at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7258)   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:7249)   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate
>   (Instrumentation.java:1222)

I can't get my head around to how this could happen. Can anyone enlighten me as to how on earth this is possible?